# PowerShell Remoting: Handling Verbose Messages

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to send the verbose output from a remote PowerShell session to the local console?

Comment: Please give some sample code. Avoid one line questions that don't give much detail.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing, but the following does get the verbose output on your console:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName comp -ScriptBlock {$verbosepreference="Continue";write-verbose "blah"}
```